# how to execute or call a method with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute a number of methods in sequence:

```
var objMethods = [JqueryAjaxViaPageMethod, JqueryWebServiceZeroParams, JqueryWebServiceOneParam, JqueryWebServiceTwoParams, JqueryWebServiceObjectParam, JqueryWebServiceClassArray];

$.each(objMethods, executeMethod(this));

  function executeMethod(methodname) {
                methodname();
                alert("done");
            }
```

this does not work, however,

singularly, this does:

```
executeMethod(JqueryAjaxViaPageMethod);
```

How do I execute the 'array' of methods?

Comment: Isn't this what `apply()` is for?

Comment: Is methodname a variable holding the method itself or just a string that contains the method's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$.each(objMethods, executeMethod(this))`, `this` most likely refers to `window`. What you are doing is calling `executeMethod` and passing the **return value** as callback to `$.each`.

I think you want:

```
$.each(objMethods, function(index, method) {
    executeMethod(method); // of course you could just do `method()` here as well
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which scope(context) they are declared

```
function executeMethod(methodname,context) {
    context = context || window; 
    context[methodname]();
    alert("done");
}
$.each(objMethods, function(){
    executeMethod(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if the methods were declared like this

```
function JqueryAjaxViaPageMethod () {
 ...
}
```

Then you can simply call the method like this

```
function executeMethod(methodname) {
  window[methodname]();
  alert("done");
}
```

---

If the methods were declared as a part of an object

```
var objMethods = {
  JqueryAjaxViaPageMethod : function () { ... },
  ...
};
```

Then you would call it like this

```
function executeMethod(methodname) {
  objMethods[methodname]();
  alert("done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your each method is wrong i guess. it should be

```
  $.each(objMethods, function(i,l) {
       executeMethod(l);
  });
```

where i = index of the element
         l = element of the index i